# Cognos TM1 connection to ClickHouse

Tags: odbc, cognos, clickhouse, cognos-tm1

Facing problems with connection Cognos Planning Analytics to database ClickHouse (https://clickhouse.tech/) via ODBC driver.

Error in tm1server.log looks like:

```
10800   [2]   ERROR   2021-08-26 14:11:42.175   TM1.SQLAPI   01000[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Cursor library not used.  Load failed
```

We use 64-bit ODBC Data Source driver provided by ClickHouse.

With the same parameters of ODBC Data Source, it turns out to connect successfully via the ODBC Connect utility(https://code.cubewise.com/odbc-connect) or via MS Excel.

Versions used:

ClickHouse server version 21.7.4.18 (official build)

IBM Cognos Planning Analytics 2.0.9.9

Comment: Based on this the https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tm1sqlapi-01000microsoftodbc-driver-manager-cursor-library-not-used-load-failed and this, https://www.tm1forum.com/viewtopic.php?t=15694... is this actually stopping you loading data? I think it's just a verbose warning, not an actual error

Comment: Nick, thank you for response. This error is stopping loading data.

Comment: If it's truly a hard stop on the data load, next step would be to enable the ODBC driver logging to see what its choking on.